# Is there a way to make my bash trap handler execute immediately?

Tags: android, bash, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to print some text to my interactive terminal when I plug an Android device into my Ubuntu 16.04 box.

The solution I've come up with involves a custom udev rule which executes a script which sends a `kill -SIGUSR1` to all bash processes on my system.

udev rule:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{adb_user}=="yes", RUN+="/bin/bash /script/location/onconnect.sh %k"
```

onconnect.sh:

```
if [[ ${*} != *":"* ]]; then
    for p in $(ps -U username | grep bash | cut -d" " -f1); do
        kill -SIGUSR1 $p
    done
fi
```

The above works. However, it seems the trap handler I've put into my environment only gets called if I hit Enter in my terminal. Is there a way to interrupt the bash thread that is waiting for a command and print immediately? The .rc file I use to install my trap looks like this:

```
...

function deviceadded() {
    echo "you've plugged in a device!"
}

trap "(deviceadded&)" SIGUSR1

...
```

On my command line, it kinda looks like this when the signal is raised:

```
[~]$
[~]$ you've plugged in a device!

[~]$ _
```

However, the text is only displayed after I hit enter. I've never used bash `trap` before, so its possible I'm just misunderstanding how it works. Is there a way to make it print immediately?

Is there a better way to approach this?

EDIT: added udev rule and udev target script.

Comment: On my system, the message is displayed immediately, but the prompt is only re-displayed after I hit the return key.  Is that what you experience too?

Comment: @Fred no, for me I need to hit enter before I see anything. Then the message prints, then I need to hit enter again to get my prompt back. The behavior you're seeing is closer to what I'd like though. I updated my post include the udev rule and the target script, maybe the delay in in there?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this happens because the command you have in trap is run in background.

Try setting the trap command just as:

```
trap deviceadded SIGUSR1
```

and see what happens.

Comment: putting the trap handler in the foreground - using your code - seems to give me the same delayed execution I'm seeing in the original post.